# VSCode image visualisation

Tags: html, css, image, url

I have a problem/question with the VSCode. Why doesn't the url of the img tag in my code work? The map is good and the other CSS code is working, the url-s of the img-s are the same...but it is not working in the VSCode's Live Server!

What is the problem? Is it a missing module, some setting, or Windows firewall?

[image]

I did not change any setting in the VSCode. Anyways it works with JSBin and CodePen.